# AJAX Fires Error No Response Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an API I am calling, all is well. I receive the token and the status code returned is a 200 (verified in Fiddler). What I am stuck on is, the AjaxError fires, but the responseText is empty. Also, complete fires successfully. I believe the label is populating, however a Postback or something is erasing it. I will see the value post to the label then disappear (some of the time). This is pure JS and HTML nothing else is being used. What gives?

```
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, options) {
            alert("HEEEY COMPLETE");
            $("#tokenLabel").html("XXXXX");
        });

        $(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr, options) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });

        $('#SubmitButton').click(function () {
            var userName = $("#userNameTextBox").val();
            var passWord = $("#passwordTextBox").val();
            populateCreds(userName, passWord);
            login();
        });

        function populateCreds(userName, passWord) {
            creds = { "Username": userName, "Password": passWord };
        }

        // Login
        function login() {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/APIService/api/token",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(creds),
                success: function (xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr.tokenValue);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOOPSIE! I'm so silly. I was using a Submit button type. So the form would be submitted and the Postback was erasing my values. Silly, silly me.

```
    <button type="button" id="SubmitButton" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

This resolved my issue.

Let me just note, that this is a single page application. If I were redirecting to another page the Submit behavior would work.